# NH ManyToOne "object is an unsaved transient instance"

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

`EntityA` has a `ManyToOne` relationship with `EntityB` using a `property-ref` attribute and `cascade="none"`.

In NH 2.1, I was able to use the following code:

```
EnttiyA a = new EntityA();
a.EntityB = new EntityB();
a.EntityB.PropertyRef = 13;
session.Save(a);
```

And it worked like a charm.
Now, after I upgraded to NH 3.2, the same code gives me the all too familiar:

```
object is an unsaved transient instance - 
save the transient instance before merging:
```

What am I doing wrong? are there any breaking-changes in the `ManyToOne` relationship between 2.1 and 3.2?

**[UPDATE]:**

Just to make the problem more clear - I **dont** want to creat a new EntityB, I want my new EntityA to have a reference to an existing EntityB with a PropertyRef  value of 13.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, it shouldn't work in 2.1. You've explicitly turned off cascading, so saving `a` does not trigger saving `a.EntityB` and `a` can't be persisted. Either call `session.Save(a.EntityB)` before saving `a` or change cascade value to at least `save`.

Comment: the order of the save shouldn't matter as long as both are saved before the flush.

Comment: No no, I dont want to save a new EntityB, I just want a's PropertyRef to be set to 13

Comment: But you're explicitly creating _new_ `EntityB`. If you want to use existing one, use `session.Load<EntityB>(13)` to load it. The fact that the relation is defined using property-ref doesn't change the way you set your objects.